# Difference between "beat in one rhythm" and "beat to one rhythm"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between "Metronomes will beat in one rhythm." and "Metronomes will beat to one rhythm"? Is it like the latter one implies the presence of the third source of rhythm?

Comment: What are they beating? If you mean the beat of the music, "They will follow/match the beat of the rhythm." might be better. You might review the definitions of [*beat*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/beat) to get a better idea about how to use it.

Comment: @user3169 - I meant intransitive sense. Like a heart's or a metronome's beating.

Comment: Could you write more complete examples, with more context? As written, it is hard to understand what is happening (what the action of "beat" is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> they will beat in one rhythm

This would imply that the subjects are "beating" in such a way that they will all create and have only one "rhythm".

> they will beat to one rhythm

This would imply that a particular rhythm ***should already*** exist and the subjects will all "beat" to it.